# Error: Can't resolve './images/sample.png' React Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, webpack

Been trying to build a MERN app with Webpack, and can't seem to load any images in React.

React component render method:

```
const logo = require('./images/sample.png');
```

`<img src={logo}'/>`

Webpack

```
module: {
loaders: [
  { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel-loader'] },
  { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader','css-loader']},
  {test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader'}
]  }
```

ouputs bundle.js into src folder, file structure below

File structure

app

|......src

.........|components

....................|component.js

.........|images

....................|sample.png

It doesn't matter how I change the path in require, and even if I put the sample.png image in the same folder as component.js I get the error that it can't be resolved. I'm thinking it must be a webpack error, but no matter how many tutorials and forums I read I can't fix it.

Ideally I would dynamically load images rather than declaring specific requires like this, so if theres a better way please tell me.

**UPDATE:**

I changed `src={logo}` to `src={require("${logo}")}`, and no longer get a server-side error. Instead, I get an error in the developer console (using Chrome) that seems to be returning the img URI (react problem?):

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'data:image/png;base64...'

Comment: can you open your image from your browser ?

Comment: and did you try having the URL to the file in the src instead of using require() ?

Comment: swap url-loader to file-loader

Comment: @Dinosan0908 1. I'm using React Router so I don't think I can navigate to the image  without maybe making a server-side route to serve it? 2. like <img src="image/sample.png"/>? Yes, no error but the image doesn't show.

Comment: @PlayMa256 I tried using both url-loader and file-loader, both individually, as well as together in webpack by configuring options for url-loader so that it would switch to file-loader over a certain image size. No lucky.

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.config.js` you need

```
const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
    },
  },
};
```

and add it here

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      imageLoaderConfiguration,
      ...
    ],
  },
```

Comment: didn't work. do you think developing in Amazon's Cloud9 has anything to do with it?

Comment: Not sure, would need to see the files in your directory.